# website hosted outside default website is not working

Tags: web-server, iis-7.5, website, web, deployment

I deployed my website as a separate webiste in IIS. It is an intranet website and is windows Authenticated

i followed the below step

- created the virtual Path for the published files.
- Right click on Sites And select "add website".
- gave FSApp as site name. Selceted app pool. gave the virtual path.
- in binding 
  left Type and Port unaltered
  selected the servers ip address in the ip section
- gave host name as "fusapp.[domain name.com]"
- checked start website immediately.
- then Clicked on OK.

Now when i right click on the website and try browse it the site is not opening.
It gives the error "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage".

Please let me know what error did i do here

our domain name is like km.com
i gave host name like fsapp.km.com
will this be an error. 
On communicating with my colleagues who have already hosted some application in the server they said that they followed similar steps to deploy their app. 
Also they didn't make any DNS entry as well it seems.
I am unsure wether application hosted without DNS entry will work. 
Please guide me on this as Well

Comment: In order to resolve the name to the ip address you MUST have a DNS record for the name.

Answer (score 1):

First, check that you have properly registered the new FQDN in the DNS: does it resolve to an IP address that is assigned to your server ?

Now, assuming you're sticking with the default port 80 for the binding and if DNS is working correctly, then did you assign a different IP address to each web site ? If not, then you will have to setup the "hostname" property of the HTTP binding of each web site to the FQDN that you want it to use.

Answer (score 1):

I'll go step by step with your post:

- There is no need to host your side under a "Virtual Directory", you just add your site files to the top level site created in IIS, adding a virtual site will force you to add a directory to your URL, for example, http://www.test.com will become http://www.test.com/nameofvirtualdirectory, notice the difference?
- If you're server have multiple sites that are separated using hostnames, you will need to create a DNS entry to link the name to the IP you used to bind the site. else your users will be unable to resolve the hostname to the IP you used.
- IIS is not that hard, I would recommend that you take a read here for all the hosting/publshing related stuff: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771341(v=ws.10).aspx

Hope this helps.